# How to detect duplicates in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to make java code that if a country already has 5 teams they cannot create more teams.

For example:

User inputs country name *asd*, then inputs team name, etc. and user does it 4 more times.

The sixth time when user inputs *asd* country name it will return an error, but if the user inputs another country name they can make another team.

I've tried using `arrayList.size()` but I still couldn't get it working.

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();

public Main() {
    int choose = 0;
    do {
        choose = displayMenu(); sc.nextLine();
        
        switch (choose) {
        case 1:
            createTeam();
            break;
        case 2:
            addMatch();
            break;
        case 3:
            showStat();
            break;
        case 4:
            showRank();
            break;
        case 5:
            eraseTeam();
            break;

        }
        
    } while (choose != 6);
    
}

    private void createTeam() {
    String country, teamName, coachName, participantName;
    System.out.print("Enter Country Name : ");
    country = sc.nextLine();
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Team Name : ");
        teamName = sc.nextLine();
        participantName = getParticipantName();
        System.out.println("Enter Coach Name : ");
        coachName = sc.nextLine();
        Team team = new Team(country, teamName, coachName, participantName);
        teams.add(team);
    } while (teams.size()>=5);
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You say you "couldnt get it working" -- what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @tgdavies what i want the program to do is find the duplicate of Country name and if there's more than 5 instances of Country name with the same name it return an error. the program above only find the size of array list Team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please tell me what does this code do for you?

At first glance, I think the problem might be in the line

```
while (teams.size()>=5)
```

If I understand it correctly, this loop will continue while the size is **at least** 5, which it is not at the beginning.

Maybe try to set it to

```
while (teams.size()<5)
```

Edit: adding the code from the comment section

1. add this under the Main class designation

`Map<String, List<Team>> countryTeams = new HashMap<String, List<Team>>();`

Read about a HashMap here for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp

2. use the HashMap in your code to match teams to countries

   private void createTeam() {
   String country, teamName, coachName, participantName;
   System.out.print("Enter Country Name : ");
   country = sc.nextLine();
   **countryTeams.put(country, new ArrayList());**
   **while (countryTeams.get(country).size()<5)** {
   System.out.print("Enter Team Name : ");
   teamName = sc.nextLine();
   participantName = getParticipantName();
   System.out.println("Enter Coach Name : ");
   coachName = sc.nextLine();
   Team team = new Team(country, teamName, coachName, participantName);
   **countryTeams.get(country).add(team);**
   }
   }

Comment: what i want the program to do is find the duplicate of Country name and if there's more than 5 instances of Country name with the same name it return an error

Comment: alright I think I got you. :))
instead of counting the countries, try to store the name in a String variable and compare that to any new given name instead.

Edit: and then you can count the matches, and when you reach 5, throw either a well handled Exception or simply break from the loop.

Comment: can you elaborate ? and can you give the example of the code if you dont mind.

Comment: thanks, but if i use that wouldn't i forced to enter 5 team for every country ? i want to enter any number of team for any country as long as it doesn't exceed 5 teams

Comment: What Michal Rosa is trying to say is when you are inserting teams, store the country inside a string variable ie String countries = "country1 country2 country1" etc... and when inserting a new team (country1), check if there are already 5 occurences of the country1 inside the string

Comment: @YHStan how can i do that ? can you explain it to me pls. thanks

Comment: You can look into a method to split the string into a String array and count the occurences of the country. It is .split(). I m also assuming you dont know how to check if strings are equal to one another, so do also look up the .equals() method

Comment: i've looked up split() and equals() method. now how am i going to implement the method in my program ?

Comment: I ll explain the logic to you. Using split() you get a string array of the countries string. From there, you can create a function that takes the name of the country you just input from createTeam and check one by one against all the Strings inside the string array and if .equals() returns true you can implement a counter. If counter hits 5, you create a logic to handle the error and not allow the new input

Comment: @YHStan

public void dupe() {
int count;
for (Team team : teams) {
String string = team.getCountry();  
System.out.println(string);
string = string.toLowerCase();  
String words[] = string.split(" ");             
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
count = 1;  
for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {  
if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {  
count++;  
}
}
 words[j] = "0";
if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")  
 System.out.println(words[i]); 
}
}
}

This is what i came out with, but it still doesnt read the duplicate what can i change to make it read the duplicates ?

Comment: you did not understand what i explained to you earlier. You do not need to iterate through the Teams again. What you do is you maintain a global variable for countries as a string, and as teams are entered through createTeam, you append the team's country into countries string.

Comment: i got it now. so i just need to make String countries="" as global variable then i can make the function private void dupe() {
String string = countries;
int count;
string = string.toLowerCase();
String words[] = string.split("@");
System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string : ");
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
count = 1;
for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {
if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {
count++;
words[j] = "0";
}
}
if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")
System.out.println(words[i]);
}
}

but then i only got the duplicate how can i make the counter ?

Comment: there is an issue with the code you are writing. Why are you comparing the values inside the string with itself? I will try giving you a pseudocode to think over. Also, currently your method is void, you can consider changing it so that you can access the result you calculated using your dupe method or consider using a global variable for count

Answer (score 0):

So I think you problem is that you are using >=. If you input 5 teams the condition is still true, cause size of teams is 5 and 5 >= 5. If you would use < it would work. So do `while (teams.size() < 5)` instead of `while (teams.size()>=5)` this.

Comment: it still doesnt work because team.size detect the arraylist of the class Team. I want to it to read the country name find the duplicate and if the countryname has 5 duplicate it return error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of what your code should be doing. I see that you are having problems with passing the result of your method back to your createTeam function, so do read into boolean methods or any other sort of method that returns a result. Also you also need to read up about taking parameters into your methods so that you can pass important values that you need to use to calculate things into the method for it to use

String countries = "country1 country1 country1 country1 country1 country2 country4";

```
    String[] country = countries.split(" ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Input a country name:");
    String inputcountry = in.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    
    for (String item : country) {
        if (item.equals(inputcountry)) {
            count++;
        }
        
        if (count >= 5) {
            System.out.println("More than 5 duplicates! Rejected!");
            break;
        }
        
    }
```